# Should I set the Tracker Name, Cookie Name, and Cookie Domain for my Tags?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

My pages are setup with multiple GA trackers:

```
ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-1', {'name': 'tracker1','cookieName': 'tracker1', 'cookieDomain':'example.org'});
ga('tracker1.send', 'pageview');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-2', {'name': 'tracker2','cookieName': 'tracker2', 'cookieDomain':'example.org'});
ga('tracker2.send', 'pageview');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXXX-3', {'name': 'tracker3','cookieName': 'tracker3', 'cookieDomain':'example.org'});
ga('tracker3.send', 'pageview');
```

In GTM, when I create Universal Analytics tags, I have the option to define the `Tracker Name`, `Cookie Name`, and `Cookie Domain`:

[image]

**Q1: Do I have to set those values, or will GTM figure those out automatically based on the `Tracking ID` I provide in the Tag?**

For the `Tracker name`, the GTM UI reads:

> Use of named trackers is highly discouraged in GTM

and points to a help page advising to use the Data Layer instead:
https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v3/reference/com/google/tagmanager/DataLayer

which says:

> you should instead update the code on your site to use the Google Tag
>   Manager dataLayer syntax. Otherwise you will be unable to configure
>   your tracking via Google Tag Manager

I've looked around but couldn't find any `GTM` `DataLayer` syntax specific for defining tracker names.

**Q2: Does someone have an example of what that syntax would be?**

Answer (score 1):

To answer this at least partly:

Since I was curious about this as well I did a quick test and created two Analytics tags with different account ids.  Looking at the GA debugger I got the output

```
Creating new tracker: gtm1403770664990
....
Creating new tracker: gtm1403770664991
```

and if I do  trackers = ga.getAll() I get two differently named trackers as well. So I'd say GTM automatically names the trackers and you do not need to enter a name yourself.

Cookie domain will be  the same for both (since they track the same domain).

The one thing I'm not sure about is the cookie name - only one cookie is created, but since this holds no info except for the client id it might very well be that this is not a problem and both trackers can user the same cookie/client id (I do not see how this would cause problems since the only requirement for the client id is that it is unique per user, which is the case even if multiple trackers use the same client id).

Comment: I can imagine that internally `GTM` or `GA` assign some random names to the trackers if you don't, unfortunately I do need to define trackers names manually in the code (as we have other coded events which alternatively interact with the different trackers), thus I'm wondering whether I also need to define those tracker names in GTM.

Comment: As for not defining cookie names, here is the issue: all trackers end up using the same cookie and thus cookies from trackers set earlier in the code are overwritten by cookie set by the last tracker. This is fine for a single website as all trackers end up using the same cookie and same client id, however when you start mixing cross sub-domain tracking (in my case tracker1 and tracker2), with top domain-specific tracking (tracker3), trackers start re-using cookies set from other websites with different client ids, which corrupts your data (e.g. incorrectly high % of new visits).

Comment: I might have misunderstood your use case - I assumed you were migrating from in-page code to GTM. If you want to keep existing trackers in your page and have additional GA tags in GTM you need to fill in the values. "Datalayer syntax" simply means to create key=>value pairs in your dataLayer and set the names using macros to make sure your page code and your GTM tags are in synch.